# Spark CSV writer outputs double quotes for empty string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've wrote UDF for Scala Spark

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
def mapToString: Map[String, Double] => String = /** // returns k1:v1,k2:v2 or empty string if map is empty */

val mapToStringUDF = udf(mapToString)

// Then I try to save my Dataset as csv
      myDataset
      .withColumn("map_str", mapToStringUDF(col("map")))
      .drop("map")
      .write
      .option("header", false)
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .csv("output.csv")
```

it outputs `""` if `mapToStringUDF` returns empty string. I want to get nothing in output if `mapToStringUDF` returned empty string.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide enough code so that we can reproduce your problem? (sample data would be great as well if needed)

Comment: could you share your sample rows from your datasets so that I can run the code and see what will be the issue.
I am getting the failure while run your code as error: not found: value myDataset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spark DataFrameWriter has two parameters for the `.csv` format option that you can set: `nullValue` and `emptyValue`, which you can both set to be `null` instead of empty strings. See the DataFrameWriter documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#csv-java.lang.String-).

In your specific example you can just add the options to your `write` statement:

```scala
myDataset
  .withColumn("map_str", mapToStringUDF(col("map")))
  .drop("map")
  .write
  .option("emptyValue", null)
  .option("nullValue", null)
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("delimiter", "\t")
  .csv("output.csv")
```

Or here's a full example, including test data:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val data = Seq(
  Row(null, "20200506", "Hello"),
  Row(2, "20200607", null),
  Row(3, null, "World")
  )

val schema = List(
  StructField("Item", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("Date", StringType, true),
  StructField("Message", StringType, true)
  )

val testDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  StructType(schema)
  )

testDF.write
  .option("emptyValue", null)
  .option("nullValue", null)
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(PATH)
```

The resulting raw `.csv` should look like this:

```
Item,Date,Message
,20151231,Hello
2,20160101,
3,,World
```

Comment: I tried with giving nullValue as null in scala and it resulted in null pointer exception.

Comment: This throws NPE if we do saveAsTable